# Install eclipse on mac failed: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

log:

```
[2019-12-26 17:48:32] 
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 11.0.5+10-LTS
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2019-12
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.15.0.v20191116-1146, build=4434, branch=3a9f8ff482882029c027d32dc59d8b0436598aa8
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.15.0.v20191103-0619, build=4434, branch=3a9f8ff482882029c027d32dc59d8b0436598aa8
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.13.0.v20191019-1424, build=4434, branch=3a9f8ff482882029c027d32dc59d8b0436598aa8
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2019-12))
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Offline = false
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Mirrors = true
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Resolving 23 requirements from 3 repositories to /Users/kiwenlau/eclipse/java-2019-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement epp.package.java [4.14.0,5.0.0)
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.14.0,5.0.0)
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.14.0,5.0.0)
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2019-12
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12/201912181000
[2019-12-26 17:48:56] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2019-12-26 17:48:58] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12/201912181000/content.xml.xz.
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
  at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:245)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
  at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:118)
  at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:70)
  at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
  at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:178)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I'm using jdk 11.0.5

```
java --version
java 11.0.5 2019-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```